# Objects appear blurry towards edge of in app camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I have implemented the new camera API for my in app camera on Android, I have a full screen camera preview that works perfectly, but I noticed that the images appear blurry just towards the edge of the camera preview. This intuitively seems like it is exactly what should happen since focus must be at the centre of the image. I want to know if there is away to define a focus area at the edge of the image or alternatively a way to bring the entire preview in focus.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried using auto focus first here is a way to do so:

```
private lateinit var cameraLocal: Camera
//...

      /**
     * Setting the right parameters in the camera
     */
    private fun applyCameraSettings(quality: Int) {
        val params = getCameraParams()
        params.setPictureSize(getDefaultWidth(), getDefaultHeight())
        params.pictureFormat = PixelFormat.JPEG
        params.jpegQuality = quality
        params.focusMode = if (params.focusMode == Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO) Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO else params.focusMode
        cameraLocal.parameters = params
    }

 /**
     * get the camera parameters
     */
    private fun getCameraParams(): Camera.Parameters {
        return cameraLocal.parameters
    }
```

Comment: I am working with the latest camera api, so I am looking at camera2 as well, and I have included the older api to cater for for <= API 21. Yes, in both cases I have enabled auto focusing. That has not helped.